# VS Code not recognizing .env file inside workspace folder (.venv)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, python-venv, python-dotenv

I'm trying to set environment variables within a Python virtual environment in VS Code (mostly for API keys). The VS Code documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments suggests that Python will automatically detect a .env file within a workspace folder. However, that doesn't seem to be happening. When I enter the following code, the terminal returns a value of None.

```
import os
SHEETY_ENDPOINT = os.getenv("SHEETY_ENDPOINT")
SHEETY_TOKEN = os.getenv("SHEETY_TOKEN")
```

I'm using the dotenv package to make the code work right now, but don't want to have to rely on it if it is unnecessary in a VS Code workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.env` file under workspace.

**.env**

```
SHEETY_ENDPOINT=someting
SHEETY_TOKEN=someting
```

Then add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

Then use shortcuts **F5** or **Debug Python File** so that you can get the environment variable stored in the `.env` file. You can also use interactive window which can work as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have an active "Python Debug Console" terminal open when you make changes to your `.env` file, you'll need to kill that terminal in order for your debug attempts to detect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Python to automatically detect a `.env` file within a workspace folder, you need to ensure that you have the Python extension installed in VS Code. Once you have the extension installed, follow these steps:

1. Open the workspace folder that you want to set the environment variables for
2. Create a file called `.env` in the root of the workspace folder.
3. Add your environment variables to the `.env` file in the following format:

```
SHEETY_ENDPOINT=your_value
SHEETY_TOKEN=your_value
```

4. Restart VS Code to apply the changes.
5. In your Python code, you can now use os.getenv to retrieve the values of the environment variables. For example:

```
import os
SHEETY_ENDPOINT = os.getenv("SHEETY_ENDPOINT")
SHEETY_TOKEN = os.getenv("SHEETY_TOKEN")
```

If you have followed these steps and are still unable to retrieve the environment variable values, then you may need to manually load the environment variables using the dotenv package or by setting them using your operating system's environment variable settings.

Answer (score 0):

Loading Environment Variables in VSCode

1. Create a .env file in your root directory. Place all your environment variables in the .env file.
   <var_name>=value
2. In your VS Code, go to settings and then python extension . Update the path of .env in the python extension.
3. Restart VS code
4. pip install python-dotenv
5. In your python code , add the following lines to load the variables from .env file:
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   load_dotenv(<filepath_of_env file>)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the debugger to launch your python app, open the .vscode/launch.json at the project root, edit the envs in `env`, e.g.

```
{
        "name": "Python: API Server",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "uvicorn",
        "args": [
            "app.main:app",
            "--port",
            "8000",
            "--host",
            "0.0.0.0"
        ],
        "env": {                
            "PORT": "8000"                
        }
    }
}
```

ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging